# Weird screen problems---iPhone 5S, iOS 8.3

Tags: iphone, ios, display, restart

I was using the "Alien Blue" reddit app on my iPhone when suddenly the app closed out and my phone turned off.

After turning the phone back on I was greeted with a flickering backlight in both lock screen and home screen. After a few soft resets, the screen flicker has gone away, but now I can not open any app. They all force quit/crash immediately. Has anyone else encountered something similar? The phone is in a LifeProof case and has never been washed, dropped, or damaged in anyway.

Details:

- Capacity: 16 GB
- Available: 5.9 GB
- Version: iOS 8.3(12F70)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by:

Resetting phone until screen flicker went away, then updated app store items. Still didn't need to upgrade to 9.0.2.